# NHibernate mapping hasmany multiple columns

Tags: nhibernate

I'm having troubles mapping has-many relation.
My relation table looks like

### Person_Id - Connected_Person_Id  - Relation_Type

```
1                        2                            1
3                        1                            2
```

I have person entity which has list of PersonConnection that relates to the relation table
the thing is that i want to map in relations when its either person_id or connected_person_id in this case for person whose id is 1 it will map both rows.

I thought of inserting the opposite row, but it seems like waste of memory.
Or I can manipulate data in the class and not in the mappings.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Personally I always add two rows as this may lead to better performance and also is more flexible if you want a uni directional relation later

Answer (score 0):

sooner or later you need to know which person initiated the connection. You can add 2 rows as Rippo suggests in the comment or map 2 collections and name them appropriately

```
// simple sample showing the idea
class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> ConnectedPersons { get; private set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> PersonsConnectingToMe { get; private set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> AllConnectedPersons { get { return ConnectedPersons.Concat(PersonsConnectingToMe); } }

    // Add Remove from collections here
}
```